# loading data from txt with repeating years with only days and months

Tags: mysql

I have a huge text file i need to upload into a mysql table

the data set spans across multiple years but the actual data only has month and day information. However the dataset is ordered starting with the most recent year. There could also be multiple data points on the same date as well.

How can I tell mysql to upload it to a table and to add the correct year?

here's an example of the kind of data i'm dealing with where the last few digits are Month:day

```
Some interesting string here             11:04
Some other interesting text              10:04
........................                 10:04

........................
Some old interesting text from last year 12:02
some boring news from last year          02:01
some news from 2 years ago               12:02
```

Comment: its the last 4 digits MM:DD

Comment: Can you open it in Excel and Add year? Or remove old data? Or Both. Sounds like an easy task.

Comment: So how are the fields delimited in your text file?  Is it fixed-space?

Comment: the lines are separated by a new line (enter key) and the reason i wanted a mysql based solution is that i have over 9000 such text files...

Comment: My question was not how are the records delimited, but rather how are the *fields* delimited?

Comment: sorry, they're delimited 2 tabs, that are in between the string and the time stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file starts in 2010, and a date that follows a later one implies the following year:

```
SET @last_mnth := 0, @year := 2010;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.txt' INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS SEPARATED BY '\t\t' (description, @d) SET
  date = CONCAT(
    LEFT(CONCAT(
      @mnth := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@d, ':',  1),
      @date := SUBSTRING_INDEX(@d, ':', -1),
      @year := @year + (
                 @mnth < @last_mnth
                 OR (@mnth = @last_mnth AND @date < @date)
               ),
      @last_mnth := @mnth
    ), 0),
    CONCAT_WS('-', @year, @mnth, @date)
  )
;
```

Here we assign your "timestamp" into a user variable `@d` and then set the `date` column equal to a string formed from the concatenation of an empty string (from `LEFT(..., 0)` in order to assign values to other, temporary, user variables) and our constructed date literal.